# can't use Acos doctrine extension in my symfony 4 project with postgres database

Tags: doctrine, api-platform.com

I'm trying to use numeric functions in my symfony 4 project.

I'm connected to postgres database :

```
DATABASE_URL=pgsql://postgres:postgres@postgres/mydatabase?serverVersion=11
```

In my doctrine.yaml file i added :

```
doctrine:
    orm:
    ...
       dql:
             numeric_functions:
                 acos: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Acos
                 cos: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Cos
                 sin: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Sin
```

I tried to make a Get resquest with postman 
I received this error message :
"Attempted to load class \"Acos\" from namespace \"DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\".\nDid you forget a \"use\" statement for another namespace?",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here you had a problem because you connected to Postgres DB, but tried to use Extension for MySQL( you can see it at the extension path 'DoctrineExtensions\Query**Mysql**\Acos' )